# Install a software using another distribution's branch

Tags: 12.04, apt

Suppose software like https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/skipfish has more recent release in 13.04, how do I add to apt-get in 12.04 to make use of that branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The page you have listed is linking to source code, which you cannot install using apt-get. However the version number of skipfish in your link is 2.10b-1, which is available in the ubuntu 13.04 universe repository, you can also manually download the .deb from here:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/skipfish and if you double click it you should be prompted to open with the ubuntu software center, which you can use to install it.